# Android: How to use Presentation class to switch between mirroring mode and dual-monitor mode?

Tags: android, mirroring, presentation, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to use  Presentation class to make an app that has a remote-controlling  UI on smart Phone and video playing on secondary display.
I know how to display directly on my secondary one, but have no idea how to go back to normal mode. Is there any code I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> have no idea how to go back to normal mode

Call `dismiss()` on the `Presentation`. If your app does not have an active `Presentation`, and if nothing else is talking to the secondary display, the default mirroring should return.